# jenkins install fail in suse,java>=1.6 is needed

Tags: java, jenkins, suse

the environment is:
suse linux enterprise server 11 x86_64
jenkins-1.563-1.2.noarch

I have manually download and installed jdk 1.6.0_45 64bit,command "java -version" succeed show the jdk version.
but when i try to install jenkins,it shows:
error failed dependencies:
java >=1.6 is needed by jenkins-1.563-1.2.noarch

anyone can help to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to install the java package which comes with Suse, or (if that's not available) install Jenkins manually.

Comment: shouldn't I install jdk before jenkins? I install jenkins using "rpm -ivh jenkins.***.rpm"

Comment: As i said, either use the rpm package for java, which you can install with the Suse package manager, or install Jenkins manually, where you can set the path to your own JDK installation. Since you have installed the JDK manually, the RPM package of Jenkins doesn't recognize your Java installation, and that's the problem.

Comment: thanks,i download jenkins.war and deploy it on tomcat. and I can access the jenkins server by http://localhost:8080/jenkins